# how to bring out a variable outside of indention?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, input, indentation

I created a program that has indention in it (you know , like for and while loops , if , elif , else , def and any another thing that has indention after it.)
and this indention has some new created variables in it. like this :

```
          .
          .
          .
little_input = input()
big_input = input()
num = 10
def calculate() :
    global num
    num += 1
    num2 = num * big_input
    num3 = num2 / little_input
    print(num3)
    rmin = num2 % little_input
    if rmin == 0 :
        print(num3)
           .
           .
           .
```

and then I saw I need to do something with the num3 variable but **it needs to be outside of the def indention.** and when it's outside , it says the variable is not defined. can you help me with this? thanks.

edit for @Nesi :

```
print("chain wheel calculator")
print("enter the little diameter in mm :")
little_input = input()
print("enter the big diameter in mm :")
big_input = input()

little_input = int(little_input)
big_input = int(big_input)

num = 9

def calculate() :
    global num
    num += 1
    num2 = num * big_input
    num3 = num2 / little_input
    print(num3)
    rmin = num2 % little_input
    if rmin == 0 :
        print(num3)

while num <= 100 :
    calculate()
```

Comment: ayo no one here to help me goodly?

Comment: Pass it in to the function as an argument.

Comment: ummm.... how????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
def calculate(num) :
    num2 = num * big_input
    num3 = num2 / little_input
    print(num3)
    rmin = num2 % little_input
    if rmin == 0 :
        print(num3)
    # after you do what you need with this function
    # you will endup with value for num3, right?
    # we will give it to the loop.
    return num3

print("chain wheel calculator")
print("enter the little diameter in mm :")
little_input = input()
print("enter the big diameter in mm :")
big_input = input()

little_input = int(little_input)
big_input = int(big_input)


num = 9
while num <= 100 :
    num3 = calculate(num)  # pass the num to function
    print(num3)
    num += 1
```

Comment: gives this error : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Green\Desktop\coding\GUI\gui.py", line 25, in <module>
    num3 = calculate(num)  # pass the num to function
TypeError: calculate() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Comment: ah.. my mistake. you see when you want your function to take a variable you must tell that to the function first, when you define it like this `def calculate(num):`

Comment: oh yea. let me add this.

Comment: why you guys did not understand me at the first? all i needed was the return statement. LOL . sorry im a beginneer in python. and i don't know some things. also thank you for all your effort.

Comment: This is printing the same result multiple times.

Comment: @ParsaAd been there, done that. :-P

Answer (score 1):

```
print("chain wheel calculator")                                                                                                                                                     
print("enter the little diameter in mm :")                                      
little_input = input()                                                          
print("enter the big diameter in mm :")                                         
big_input = input()                                                             
                                                                                
little_input = int(little_input)                                                
big_input = int(big_input)                                                      
                                                                                
num = 9                                                                         
                                                                                
def calculate(little_input, big_input, num):                                    
    num2 = num * big_input                                                      
    num3 = num2 / little_input                                                  
    rmin = num2 % little_input                                                  
    if rmin == 0:                                                               
        return num3                                                             
                                                                                
while num <= 100 :                                                              
    num3 = calculate(little_input, big_input, num)                              
    if num3:                                                                    
        print(num3)                                                             
    num += 1
```

this should work. I am not sure what behaviour you want but I presume you only want to return `num3` if `rmin == 0`. If `rmin != 0` this will return `None`. So the statement `if num3:` checks if num3 is not `None` type and then prints the resulting value. You can add in whatever you wish to do to `num3` within this conditional statement. Generally, aviod mixing scopes like you were doing before.

Comment: I don't need any changes. my problem is just how to bring out that num3 variable outside of def function scope.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to declare it outside the function then inside the function use it as global variable.

Here a [link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_variables_global.asp) that might help you.

Here an example

```
num3= 0


def calculate():
        global num3
        num3 = 133131





print(f"Num3 before calling func : {num3}")
calculate()
print(f"Num3 after calling func : {num3}")
```

Output that i got

```
Num3 before calling func : 0
Num3 after calling func : 133131
```

Comment: but i cannot declare it outside of function. i need to do it inside

Comment: why you cannot ?

Comment: because i need to loop this function and if they are outside i cannot loop

Comment: You can. Please check the link that i added

Comment: i put this function inside a while loop and it loops forever. like : while True     calculate()

Comment: ok i'll check...

Comment: i just added an example. Can you try it ?

Comment: Why are you even defining these as global variables. Write your function to take the variables as an argument, perform your calculation in the scope of the function and return what is needed from the function to the global scope.

Comment: @kyle the problem is there that i cannot return the num3 from def scope to global scope

Comment: @nabil like how i said , all this needs to be in the def indention. your example won't work because im looping these

Comment: Can you show the code, both function (def) and your while loop. What does the function return?

Comment: @Nesi here it is. but like how i said i want to change the num variable in last while loop to num3 variable